# How to cache react component in client side?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to cache react component in client side. If a user comes a page say **A** and then navigate to another page say **B**, when again he comes back to **A** I want render should not execute ,no api call should be executed, the page should be served from cache .

Comment: this approach is going to violate react life cycle hook

Comment: @SangramBadi:  React generates html in the browser, with this approach we would be memoization the rendered component, instead of recalculation

Answer (score 0):

You can cache `state`

```
let cachedState = null;

class ExampleComponent extend React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = cachedState !== null ? cachedState : {
            apiData: null
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        cachedState = this.state;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.apiData === null) {
            this.loadApiData()
                .then(apiData => {
                    this.setState({apiData});
                });
        }
    }

    loadApiData = () => {
        // code to load apiData
    };
}
```

Comment: This is data caching but i'm talking about entire page caching is that possible.

Comment: React is data-driven, we should render pages from data. I think that save the state of the page is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the input props are not getting changed, you can use React.memo().
**(This is not useMemo Hook. Please don't get confused)**

```
const Greeting = React.memo(props => {
  console.log("Greeting Comp render");
  return <h1>Hi {props.name}!</h1>;
});
```

Read this article for further clarifications -> https://linguinecode.com/post/prevent-re-renders-react-functional-components-react-memo